# Hiding/showing a sticky menu div on resize using javascript and media queries

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I want to achieve is to have a menu bar stuck to the top only when browser window is at least 980px wide. When the window is resized to less than 980px of width there should be no sticky menu showing. Then, resizing it to more that 980px of width, the menu should appear again.

Here's my code:

```js
var backup = $("#moving_topbar");
var buffer;
var mql = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 980px)");
mql.addListener(showhidemenu);
showhidemenu(mql);

function showhidemenu(mql) {
  if (mql.matches) {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      backup.append(buffer);
      if ($(window).scrollTop() > 96) {
        $("#moving_topbar").show();
      } else {
        $("#moving_topbar").hide();
      }
    });
  } else {
    backup = $("#moving_topbar");
    buffer = $("#moving_topbar").detach();
  }
}
```

```css
/*those are inside separate css files*/

#moving_topbar {
  /*wide.css*/
  position: fixed;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #15d6a7;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Verdana;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: none;
}

#moving_topbar {
  /*narrow.css*/
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" media='screen and (min-width: 980px)' href="wide.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media='screen and (max-width: 979px)' href="narrow.css" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<div id="moving_topbar">
  <div id="logodiv"> <img src="img/logo100.png" alt="Logo" class="rounded_corners_moving"> </div>
  <div id="socialtop_moving">
    <div class="soc_icon_moving">
      <!-- a, img (not important) -->
    </div>
    <div class="soc_icon_moving">
      <!-- a, img (not important) -->
    </div>
    <div class="soc_icon_moving">
      <!-- a, img (not important) -->
    </div>
    <div class="soc_icon_moving">
      <!-- a, img (not important) -->
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"> </div>
  </div>
  <div id="menu_moving">
    <div class="option_moving"> <b> ZAGRAJ </b> </div>
    <div class="option_moving"> <b> PROJEKTY </b> </div>
    <div class="option_moving"> <b> ARTYKUŁY </b> </div>
    <div class="option_moving"> <b> ENG </b> </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"> </div>
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both;"> </div>
</div>
</body>
```

The problem is that when I f5 the window on fullscreen it works ok, then I reduce its width and no bar shows (ok) but after this, when I increase the width (fullscreen) again, no sticky topbar menu appears.

When I f5 with window width smaller than 980px (no topbar here - ok) and then fullscreen, the menu shows and follows on scrolling. Then I perform the steps described above and the same problem occurs.

Maybe this is just a stupid mistake I somehow  missed but I believe this occurs due to my poor experience with javascript/jQuery.

Working code recreation:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<head>
    <style>
    @media screen and (min-width: 980px)
    {
        #topbar
        {
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            width: 100%;
            height: 120px;
            background-color: #15d6a7;
            font-size: 20px;
            font-family: Verdana;
            color: #000000;
        }

        #moving_topbar
        {
            position: fixed;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            width: 100%;
            height: 80px;
            background-color: #15d6a7;
            font-size: 20px;
            font-family: Verdana;
            color: #000000;
            display: none;
        }
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 979px)
    {
        #topbar
        {
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            width: 100%;
            padding-top: 14px;
            padding-bottom: 1px;
            background-color: #15d6a7;
            font-size: 20px;
            font-family: Verdana;
            color: #000000;
        }

        #moving_topbar
        {
            display: none;
        }
    }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var backup = $("#moving_topbar"); 
        var buffer;
        var mql = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 980px)");
        mql.addListener(showhidemenu);
        showhidemenu(mql);

        function showhidemenu(mql)
        {
            if (mql.matches)
            {
                $(window).scroll(function()
                {
                    backup.append(buffer);
                    if($(window).scrollTop() > 96) { $("#moving_topbar").show(); }
                    else { $("#moving_topbar").hide(); }
                });
            }
            else
            {
                backup = $("#moving_topbar");
                buffer = $("#moving_topbar").detach();
            }
        }       
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="moving_topbar">
        <div id="logodiv"> img logo </div>
        <div id="socialtop_moving">
            <div class="soc_icon_moving"> moving img 1 </div>
            <div class="soc_icon_moving"> moving img 2 </div>
            <div class="soc_icon_moving"> moving img 3 </div>
            <div class="soc_icon_moving"> moving img 4 </div>
            <div style="clear:both;"> </div>
        </div>
        <div id="menu_moving"> 
            <div class="option_moving"> <b> moving menu 1 </b> </div>
            <div class="option_moving"> <b> moving menu 2 </b> </div>
            <div class="option_moving"> <b> moving menu 3 </b> </div>
            <div class="option_moving"> <b> moving menu 4</b> </div>
            <div style="clear:both;"> </div>
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both;"> </div>
    </div>

    <div id="topbar">
        <div id="logodiv"> some img </div>
        <div id="socialtop">
            <div class="soc_icon"> a, img </div>
            <div class="soc_icon"> a, img </div>
            <div class="soc_icon"> a, img </div>
            <div class="soc_icon"> a, img </div>
            <div style="clear:both;"> </div>
        </div>
        <div id="menu"> 
            <div class="option"> <b> menu1 </b> </div>
            <div class="option"> <b> menu2 </b> </div>
            <div class="option"> <b> menu3 </b> </div>
            <div class="option"> <b> menu4 </b> </div>
            <div style="clear:both;"> </div>
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both;"> </div>
    </div>

    <div style="width:500px;color:grey;">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris mi sapien,
    sollicitudin id molestie eu, dignissim vel tellus. Sed ut lorem dignissim, pharetra arcu ut, porttitor mi.
    Nullam ac lacinia est. Ut iaculis felis dui, et tincidunt est mollis sed. In consectetur convallis mi, sed gravida arcu laoreet varius.
    In ac tincidunt velit. Vivamus et sollicitudin lorem, et fringilla nulla.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris mi sapien,
    sollicitudin id molestie eu, dignissim vel tellus. Sed ut lorem dignissim, pharetra arcu ut, porttitor mi.
    Nullam ac lacinia est. Ut iaculis felis dui, et tincidunt est mollis sed. In consectetur convallis mi, sed gravida arcu laoreet varius.
    In ac tincidunt velit. Vivamus et sollicitudin lorem, et fringilla nulla.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris mi sapien,
    sollicitudin id molestie eu, dignissim vel tellus. Sed ut lorem dignissim, pharetra arcu ut, porttitor mi.
    Nullam ac lacinia est. Ut iaculis felis dui, et tincidunt est mollis sed. In consectetur convallis mi, sed gravida arcu laoreet varius.
    In ac tincidunt velit. Vivamus et sollicitudin lorem, et fringilla nulla.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris mi sapien,
    sollicitudin id molestie eu, dignissim vel tellus. Sed ut lorem dignissim, pharetra arcu ut, porttitor mi.
    Nullam ac lacinia est. Ut iaculis felis dui, et tincidunt est mollis sed. In consectetur convallis mi, sed gravida arcu laoreet varius.
    In ac tincidunt velit. Vivamus et sollicitudin lorem, et fringilla nulla.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris mi sapien,
    sollicitudin id molestie eu, dignissim vel tellus. Sed ut lorem dignissim, pharetra arcu ut, porttitor mi.
    Nullam ac lacinia est. Ut iaculis felis dui, et tincidunt est mollis sed. In consectetur convallis mi, sed gravida arcu laoreet varius.
    In ac tincidunt velit. Vivamus et sollicitudin lorem, et fringilla nulla.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris mi sapien,
    sollicitudin id molestie eu, dignissim vel tellus. Sed ut lorem dignissim, pharetra arcu ut, porttitor mi.
    Nullam ac lacinia est. Ut iaculis felis dui, et tincidunt est mollis sed. In consectetur convallis mi, sed gravida arcu laoreet varius.
    In ac tincidunt velit. Vivamus et sollicitudin lorem, et fringilla nulla.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris mi sapien,
    sollicitudin id molestie eu, dignissim vel tellus. Sed ut lorem dignissim, pharetra arcu ut, porttitor mi.
    Nullam ac lacinia est. Ut iaculis felis dui, et tincidunt est mollis sed. In consectetur convallis mi, sed gravida arcu laoreet varius.
    In ac tincidunt velit. Vivamus et sollicitudin lorem, et fringilla nulla.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris mi sapien,
    sollicitudin id molestie eu, dignissim vel tellus. Sed ut lorem dignissim, pharetra arcu ut, porttitor mi.
    Nullam ac lacinia est. Ut iaculis felis dui, et tincidunt est mollis sed. In consectetur convallis mi, sed gravida arcu laoreet varius.
    In ac tincidunt velit. Vivamus et sollicitudin lorem, et fringilla nulla.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris mi sapien,
    sollicitudin id molestie eu, dignissim vel tellus. Sed ut lorem dignissim, pharetra arcu ut, porttitor mi.
    Nullam ac lacinia est. Ut iaculis felis dui, et tincidunt est mollis sed. In consectetur convallis mi, sed gravida arcu laoreet varius.
    In ac tincidunt velit. Vivamus et sollicitudin lorem, et fringilla nulla.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris mi sapien,
    sollicitudin id molestie eu, dignissim vel tellus. Sed ut lorem dignissim, pharetra arcu ut, porttitor mi.
    Nullam ac lacinia est. Ut iaculis felis dui, et tincidunt est mollis sed. In consectetur convallis mi, sed gravida arcu laoreet varius.
    In ac tincidunt velit. Vivamus et sollicitudin lorem, et fringilla nulla.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris mi sapien,
    sollicitudin id molestie eu, dignissim vel tellus. Sed ut lorem dignissim, pharetra arcu ut, porttitor mi.
    Nullam ac lacinia est. Ut iaculis felis dui, et tincidunt est mollis sed. In consectetur convallis mi, sed gravida arcu laoreet varius.
    In ac tincidunt velit. Vivamus et sollicitudin lorem, et fringilla nulla.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris mi sapien,
    sollicitudin id molestie eu, dignissim vel tellus. Sed ut lorem dignissim, pharetra arcu ut, porttitor mi.
    Nullam ac lacinia est. Ut iaculis felis dui, et tincidunt est mollis sed. In consectetur convallis mi, sed gravida arcu laoreet varius.
    In ac tincidunt velit. Vivamus et sollicitudin lorem, et fringilla nulla
    </div>
</body>
```

Sorry for this long lorem ipsum but it's necessary to make the page scrollable. Also forgive me but I have no idea how to format the code properly.

Comment: There is one already. What do you mean? I added css for narrow window and html (what my moving div contains) but the html is not so important I believe.

Comment: can't you write media query ?? you can easily achieve by css

Comment: Show/hide moving div is unachievable by css as far as I know. This div is not displayed all the time.
I want to show/hide and move it only when the window is at least 980px wide. It should not be displayed in narrower window.
Too bad, the change happens only once. The menu does not come back to its default status (to be shown or not).

Comment: You will need to provide a code that can recreate the problem.

Comment: Done. I have no idea hot to apply "run code snippet" button, sorry for that.
Try to f5 when window is narrow or wide, then resize a couple of times and scroll every time after resizing. You should get what my problem is.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by using media queries, try this.

```
   @media screen and (max-width: 980px) 
   {
   #moving_topbar 
    {
        display: none;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, I solved this already some weeks ago. I reengineered the code completely and achieved what I wanted.